# Aggregate data in CSV file using Java

Tags: java, csv

I have a big CSV file, thousands of rows, and I want to aggregate some columns using java code.

The file in the form:

```
1,2012,T1
2,2015,T2
3,2013,T1
4,2012,T1
```

The results should be:

```
T, Year, Count
T1,2012, 2
T1,2013, 1
T2,2015, 1
```

Comment: I tried different methods, but insufficient. I'm looking for faster approach.

Comment: @Programmer So you are looking for a faster approach, but we don't even know what your current approach is. Can you post at least a sketch of the approaches you've come up with so we can help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your data to a Map like structure, each time add +1 to a stored value when a key (in your case ""+T+year) found.

Comment: Should I use String and Integer in the map, or how could I increase the counter when there is matching?

Comment: For each row create a following string: ""+t+year (here t is value for T) . The result will be String. For example `String t="T1"; Integer year=2012; String result = "" + t + year; //result = "T12012"`. Then put result to a map (`Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();`) but before putting check if an entry exists `if (m.containsKey(result)) {m.put(result,m.get(result)+1);} else {m.put(result,1);} `

Answer (score 0):

You can use map like

```
Map<String, Integer> rowMap = new HashMap<>();
rowMap("T1", 1);
rowMap("T2", 2);
rowMap("2012", 1);
```

or you can define your own class with T and Year field by overriding hashcode and equals method. Then you can use

```
Map<YourClass, Integer> map= new HashMap<>();
```

T1,2012, 2

Answer (score 0):

```
    String csv =
           "1,2012,T1\n"
         + "2,2015,T2\n"
         + "3,2013,T1\n"
         + "4,2012,T1\n";
    Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(csv));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] fields = line.split(",");
        String key = fields[2] + "," + fields[1];
        Integer value = map.get(key);
        if (value == null)
            value = 0;
        map.put(key, value + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
    // -> {T1,2012=2, T1,2013=1, T2,2015=1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) for the best performance. It should take 1 second to process 1 million rows.

```
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.selectIndexes(1, 2); //select the columns we are going to read

    final Map<List<String>, Integer> results = new LinkedHashMap<List<String>, Integer>(); //stores the results here

    //Use a custom implementation of RowProcessor
    settings.setRowProcessor(new AbstractRowProcessor() {
        @Override
        public void rowProcessed(String[] row, ParsingContext context) {
            List<String> key = Arrays.asList(row); // converts the input array to a List - lists implement hashCode and equals based on their values so they can be used as keys on your map.

            Integer count = results.get(key);
            if (count == null) {
                count = 0;
            }
            results.put(key, count + 1);
        }
    });

    //creates a parser with the above configuration and RowProcessor
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

    String input = "1,2012,T1"
            + "\n2,2015,T2"
            + "\n3,2013,T1"
            + "\n4,2012,T1";

    //the parse() method will parse and submit all rows to your RowProcessor - use a FileReader to read a file instead the String I'm using as example.
    parser.parse(new StringReader(input));

    //Here are the results:
    for(Entry<List<String>, Integer> entry : results.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " -> " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

Output:

```
[2012, T1] -> 2
[2015, T2] -> 1
[2013, T1] -> 1
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).